# How to open .rdl reports file in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013

I am having an issue in opening the report file in Visual Studio 2013. When I try to open the solution file, it states that:

[image]

The error message which I am getting is:

[image]

The version of visual studio which I am using is:

[image]

I am wondering what extra package we need to install in order to open the reports file in visual studio 2013 ?

The version of visual studio 2013 as mentioned above in the image is `12.0.40629.00 Update 5`

Comment: Do you have [SSDT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313) installed?

Comment: Yes, its installed.

Comment: @ChrisAlbert I have installed from the same link.

Comment: @ChrisAlbert When I installed the SSDT from the same link, now instead of  `incompatible it says unavailable`

Comment: @ChrisAlbert In my first image, it states that it is `incompatible`. Now it is `unavailable` after installing SSDT.

Comment: @ChrisAlbert Also after installing  `SSDT for Visual Studio 2013`, now from the start menu I can see `SSDT for Visual Studio 2013` instead of 'Visual Studio 2013'.